# How to generate and return a PDF file from in-memory buffer using FastAPI?

Tags: python, pdf-generation, fastapi, pyfpdf, fileresponse

I generate a PDF file using `PyFPDF` library and would like to return this in-memory buffer without writing it to local disk.

```python
@app.post("/pdf")
def generate_report(id_worker: int = Form(...),  start_date: date = Form(...), end_date: date = Form(...)):
    user = [id_worker]
    start_date = datetime(start_date.year, start_date.month, start_date.day)
    end_date = datetime(end_date.year, end_date.month, end_date.day)
    attendance = filter_by_date(zk, user, start_date, end_date)
    user_history = attendance_to_dict(attendance)
    dates, data, days, errors, updated_history = data_to_july(user_history, start_date, end_date)
    pdf = create_user_pdf(updated_history, start_date, end_date, days, errors)
    pdf_temp = "attendance.pdf"
    pdf.output(pdf_temp)
    name = "report.pdf"

    return FileResponse(pdf_temp, media_type="application/pdf", filename=name)
```

I've tried the following; however, without success:

```python
name = "report.pdf"
pdf_buff = io.BytesIO()
pdf.output(pdf_buff)
pdf_buff.seek(0)
return FileResponse(pdf_buff.getvalue(), media_type="application/pdf", filename=name)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return a PDF file from in-memory buffer using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585779/how-to-return-a-pdf-file-from-in-memory-buffer-using-fastapi)

Comment: @Chris, sadly not. I tried using it and I get an empty pdf file.

Comment: They use a different method for the pdf, in that answer the pdf is already in memory but I don't know which kind, is it string or iobyte. I tried that one and I'm getting an oupuit of 0kb on my pdf file

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't suggest using `PyFPDF`, as it is **outdated** and no longer being maintained. Instead, you could use [`fpdf2`](https://github.com/PyFPDF/fpdf2) (see the [documentation](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/) as well), which is a fork and the successor of `PyFPDF`, as well as has very similar syntax. You could install it as follows:

```
pip install fpdf2
```

As described in [this tutorial](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/Tutorial.html#tuto-1-minimal-example), when calling [`FPDF.output()`](https://pyfpdf.github.io/fpdf2/fpdf/fpdf.html#fpdf.fpdf.FPDF.output) without providing any filepath parameter, the function returns the PDF `bytearray` buffer, which you could convert to a `bytes` object using the `bytes()` function and pass it to a [custom `Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-directly/#returning-a-custom-response) (if you need to return it as part of a Jinja2 template, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76195586/17865804)). As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804), to have the PDF file *viewed* in the browser, you could set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header as follows:

```py
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="out.pdf"'}
```

Alternatively, to have the PDF file *downloaded* rather than *viewed* in the borwser, use:

```py
headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="out.pdf"'}
```

Here are two options on how to generate and return a PDF file from a FastAPI endpoint. The first option uses an endpoint defined with normal `def`, while the second option uses an `async def` endpoint. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) to understand the difference between the two, as well as how FastAPI handles requests for normal `def` endpoints compared to `async def` endpoints.

### Option 1 - Using `def` endpoint

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fpdf import FPDF

app = FastAPI()


def create_PDF(text):
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('helvetica', 'B', 16)
    pdf.cell(10, 30, text)
    return pdf.output()

    
@app.get('/')
def get_pdf():
    out = create_PDF('Hello World!')
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="out.pdf"'}
    return Response(bytes(out), headers=headers, media_type='application/pdf')
```

### Option 2 - Using `async def` endpoint

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
from fpdf import FPDF
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures

app = FastAPI()


def create_PDF(text):
    pdf = FPDF()
    pdf.add_page()
    pdf.set_font('helvetica', 'B', 16)
    pdf.cell(10, 30, text)
    return pdf.output()
    

@app.get('/')
async def get_pdf():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
        out = await loop.run_in_executor(pool, create_PDF, 'Hello World!')
        
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="out.pdf"'}
    return Response(bytes(out), headers=headers, media_type='application/pdf')
```

Comment: I have also been downloaded for fun. The administrators should fix this misbehaviours

Comment: @Chris, it is a pity, I upvoted, I will use in the future fpdf2, thanks a lot

Comment: @Chris, I tried your solution, it works but still the encoding needs to be 'latin-1', otherwise it doesn't

Comment: :@Ukhu Please first uninstall `PyFPDF` (`pip uninstall fpdf`), as it would clash with `fpdf2`.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with this.

```python
@app.post("/pdf")
def generate_report(id_worker: int = Form(...),  start_date: date = Form(...), end_date: date = Form(...)):
    user = [id_worker]
    start_date = datetime(start_date.year, start_date.month, start_date.day)
    end_date = datetime(end_date.year, end_date.month, end_date.day)
    attendance = filter_by_date(zk, user, start_date, end_date)
    user_history = attendance_to_dict(attendance)
    dates, data, days, errors, updated_history = data_to_july(user_history, start_date, end_date)
    pdf = create_user_pdf(updated_history, start_date, end_date, days, errors)
    pdf_string = pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1')
    pdf_buff = io.BytesIO(pdf_string)
    pdf_bytes = pdf_buff.getvalue()
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="out.pdf"'}
    return Response(pdf_bytes, headers=headers, media_type='application/pdf')
```

I used @Chris' suggestion [fastapi from buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73585779/how-to-return-a-pdf-file-from-in-memory-buffer-using-fastapi), [fpdf to bytes](https://github.com/reingart/pyfpdf/issues/19#issuecomment-89058683) and [encoding fpdf](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/output/index.html) to make everything work