# How to zip multiple csv files into archive and return it in FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, zip, fastapi

I'm attempting to compose a response to enable the download of reports. I retrieve the relevant data through a database query and aim to store it in memory to avoid generating unnecessary files on the server. My current challenge involves saving the CSV file within a zip file. Regrettably, I've spent several hours on this issue without finding a satisfactory solution, and I'm uncertain about the specific mistake I may be making. The CSV file in question is approximately 40 MB in size.

This is my FastAPI code. I successfully saved the CSV file locally, and all the data within it is accurate. I also managed to correctly create a zip file containing the CSV. However, the FastAPI response is not behaving as expected. After downloading it returns me zip with error:

> The ZIP file is corrupted, or there's an unexpected end of the archive.

```
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends
from sqlalchemy import text
from libs.auth_common import veryfi_admin
from libs.database import database
import csv
import io
import zipfile
from fastapi.responses import Response

router = APIRouter(
    tags=['report'],
    responses={404: {'description': 'not found'}}
)


@router.get('/raport', dependencies=[Depends(veryfi_admin)])
async def get_raport():
    query = text(
        """
            some query
        """
    )

    data_de = await database.fetch_all(query)

    csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
    csv_writer_de = csv.writer(csv_buffer, delimiter=';', lineterminator='\n')

    csv_writer_de.writerow([
        "id", "name", "date", "stock",
    ])

    for row in data_de:
        csv_writer_de.writerow([
            row.id,
            row.name,
            row.date,
            row.stock,

        ])
    csv_buffer.seek(0)

    zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
        zip_file.writestr("data.csv", csv_buffer.getvalue())

    response = Response(content=zip_buffer.getvalue())
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] = "attachment; filename=data.zip"
    response.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/zip"
    response.headers["Content-Length"] = str(len(zip_buffer.getvalue()))

    print("CSV Buffer Contents:")
    print(csv_buffer.getvalue())
    return response
```

Here is also the vue3 code

```
const downloadReport = () => {
  loading.value = true;
  instance
    .get(`/raport`)
    .then((res) => {
      const blob = new Blob([res.data], { type: "application/zip" });
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      link.download = "raport.zip";
      link.click();
      loading.value = false;
    })
    .catch(() => (loading.value = false));
};
<button @click="downloadReport" :disabled="loading">
      Download Report
</button>
```

Thank you for your understanding as I navigate through my first question on this platform.

Comment: did you try with [StreamingResponse](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=fileresponse#streamingresponse) or [FileResponse](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/?h=fileresponse#fileresponse)?

Comment: Yes I tried with StreamingResponse and FileResponse but it didn't work either @AminTaghikhani

Comment: May I ask the reason of returning a `zip` instead of `csv` file?

Comment: Because there will be several queries and I would like to save all the csv to one zip to make it easier to download them. @Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a working example on how to create multiple `csv` files, then compress them into a `zip` file, and finally, return the `zip` file to the user. This answer makes use of code and concepts previously discussed in the following answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70653605/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73694164/17865804). Thus, I would suggest having a look at those answers for more details.

Also, since the `zipfile` module's operations are *synchronous*, you should define the endpoint with normal `def` instead of `async def`, unless you used some third-party library that provides an `async` API as well, or you had to `await` for some coroutine (`async def` function) inside the endpoint, in which case I would suggest running the `zipfile`'s operations in an external `ThreadPool` (since they are blocking IO-bound operations). Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for relevant solutions, as well as details on `async` / `await` and how FastAPI deals with `async def` and normal `def` API endpoints.

Further, you don't really need using `StreamingResponse`, if the data are already loaded into memory, as shown in the example below. You should instead return a custom `Response` (see the example below, as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76197700/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71643439/17865804) for more details).

Note that the example below uses `utf-16` encoding on the `csv` data, in order to make it compatible with data that include unicode or non-ASCII characters, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77585366/17865804). If there's none of such characters in your data, `utf-8` encoding could be used as well.

Also, note that for demo purposes, the example below loops through a `list` of `dict` objects to write the `csv` data, in order to make it more easy for you to adapt it to your database query data case. Otherwise, one could also `csv.DictWriter()` and its `writerows()` method, as demosntrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77585366/17865804), in order to write the data, instead of looping through the `list`.

### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, BackgroundTasks, Response
import zipfile
import csv
import io


app = FastAPI()


fake_data = [
  {
    "Id": "1",
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": "20",
    "height": "62",
    "weight": "120.6"
  },
  {
    "Id": "2",
    "name": "Freddie",
    "age": "21",
    "height": "74",
    "weight": "190.6"
  }
]


def create_csv(data: list):
    s = io.StringIO()
    try:
        writer = csv.writer(s, delimiter='\t')
        writer.writerow(data[0].keys())
        for row in data:
            writer.writerow([row['Id'], row['name'], row['age'], row['height'], row['weight']])
        s.seek(0)
        return s.getvalue().encode('utf-16')
    except:
        raise HTTPException(detail='There was an error processing the data', status_code=400)
    finally:
        s.close()


@app.get('/')
def get_data():
    zip_buffer = io.BytesIO()
    try:
        with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_buffer, 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip_file:
            for i in range(5):
                zip_info = zipfile.ZipInfo(f'data_{i}.csv')
                csv_data = create_csv(fake_data)
                zip_file.writestr(zip_info, csv_data)
            
        zip_buffer.seek(0)
        headers = {"Content-Disposition": "attachment; filename=files.zip"}
        return Response(zip_buffer.getvalue(), headers=headers, media_type="application/zip")
    except:
        raise HTTPException(detail='There was an error processing the data', status_code=400)
    finally:
        zip_buffer.close()
```