# FastAPI - How to specify filename when downloading bytes content using Response class?

Tags: file, download, fastapi, response, starlette

I need to download files stored in MongoDB (and not in file system) using FastAPI.
I use FastAPI `Response` for this, because `FileResponse` can only be used if files are in the file system. Downloading works, but I cannot find a way to specify the `filename` when downloading it.

Downloading works, but filename is by default `response_SOME-NUMBER.txt` (from Swagger).

Here's the code.

```py
@app.get("/files/{file_name}", responses = {200: {"content": {"text/html": {}}}}, response_class = Response)
def download_file(file_name: str):
    with MongoClient() as client:
        files_collection = client[DB][FILES_COLLECTION]
        result = files_collection.find_one({"file_name": file_name})
        content = result["file_data"]

    if result is not None:
        return Response(content=content, media_type="text/html")
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="File not found")
```

I guess I can add the name in the headers to be retrieved by the UI, like this:

```py
headers = {'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{download_file_name}"'}
return Response(content=content, headers=headers, media_type="text/html")
```

But I would like to know if there is a way to do specify the name similarly to `FileResponse`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it has been previously described in the following answers:

1. [How to upload a csv file using Jinja2 Templates and FastAPI , and return it after modifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588435/17865804)
2. [How to return a PDF file from in-memory buffer using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73586180/17865804)
3. [How to return and download Excel file using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72053557/17865804)
4. [Download PDF file using pdfkit and FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728386/17865804)
5. [How do I download a file from FastAPI backend using JavaScript
   Fetch API in the frontend?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804)
6. [How to generate and return a PDF file from in-memory buffer using
   FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76197700/17865804)
7. [How to Download a File after POSTing data using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804)
8. [How to have the dialog box for choosing download location appeared
   in the frontend, before the file gets downloaded, using FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77718453/17865804)
9. [How to display a Matplotlib chart with FastAPI/ Nextjs without saving the chart locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73754985/17865804)
10. [Render NumPy array in FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804)

when returning a `Response` instance, one could set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) response header, indicating whether a file should be *displayed* inside the browser/webpage (using `inline` as the value for the first parameter in the header, which is the default) or *downloaded* (using `attachment`), as well as specify the `filename` (which is optional) when the file is downloaded to the client's device.

**Note** that "the string following `filename` should always be put into quotes; but, for compatibility reasons, many browsers try to parse unquoted names that contain spaces" (if the `filename` contains unicode characters, one should instead use the `filename*` parameter and encode the filename value—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195901/17865804)).

#### Example

```py
from FastAPI import Response
...

# use this, if you would like to have the file displayed inside the browser instead
# headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="out.html"'}

headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="out.html"'}
return Response(content=content, headers=headers, media_type='text/html')
```

When returning a [`FileResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse)—which inherits from [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response), as every other response class in FastAPI/Starlette—and setting the `filename` parameter, FastAPI/Starlette, behind the scenes, actually sets the `Content-Disposition` header for you. This can be seen in the implementation of `FileResponse` class [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/554f368809e0d891a699667faf0cfbb20057eeb2/starlette/responses.py#L271):

```py
class FileResponse(Response):
    chunk_size = 64 * 1024

    def __init__(
        self,
        ...
        headers: typing.Mapping[str, str] | None = None,
        filename: str | None = None,
        content_disposition_type: str = "attachment",
    ) -> None:
        ...
        self.filename = filename
        ...
        self.init_headers(headers)
        if self.filename is not None:
            content_disposition_filename = quote(self.filename)
            if content_disposition_filename != self.filename:
                content_disposition = "{}; filename*=utf-8''{}".format(
                    content_disposition_type, content_disposition_filename
                )
            else:
                content_disposition = '{}; filename="{}"'.format(
                    content_disposition_type, self.filename
                )
            self.headers.setdefault("content-disposition", content_disposition)
```

As explained earlier, and as shown in the implementation of `FileResponse` above, Starlette will check if the `filename` value passed contains non-ascii/unicode characters, and if so, it will use the `filename*` parameter instead and send the value encoded.

Hence, in your case, you could either set the `Content-Disposition` header on your own (which might be the most suitable solution), as demonstrated in the example earlier, or implement your own custom response class, inheriting from Starlette's `Response`, which would accept bytes `content` and a `filename` parameter for setting the header as in `FileResponse` above.

Comment: Thanks for the links, I did read most of them, where I found the Content-Disposition information. I wanted to know if there was another way to specify the name, and you basically confirm there is not, since a custom response class would just simplify the Content-Disposition header creation.